# Sub strings, grabbing a piece in the middle, with random sizes

Tags: c++, string, substring, substr

I have a file with outputs like so,

```
Joel[12813/76561198008530803] was taken by Huey[3924/252820590256923]
```

I have set up a `getline` that will scan for the word taken and store it into a string, I tried using `substr` but I'm having an issue. The issue is that the numbers between the brackets can be different sizes so when I try something along the lines of `find_first_of("/");` in combination with `substr`, I can't use the second parameter or it might cut off numbers. I get everything past the first forward slash.

What I want in the end is to extract just this portion `76561198008530803` of the string.

What I tried,

```
while (getline(read, line))
{
    if (line.find("taken") != string::npos) {
        size_t pos = line.find_first_of("/");
        extension = line.substr(pos + 1);
        output << extension << endl;
    }
```

Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You could use `std::regex`.

Comment: Is there a huge difference here? I looked at regex and it looks pretty identical, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: The difference is you can match and extract whole substrings directly from a group defined in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::string::find_first_of` repeatedly.

```
    size_t pos = line.find_first_of("/");       
    size_t pos2 = line.find_first_of("]");
    std::string  extension = line.substr(pos + 1,pos2-1-pos);
```